# Building a primitive debugger in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, debugging, process-monitoring

I'd like to build a primitive debugger in Visual C++ that does few basic things:

1) Attaches to a running process.
2) Sets breakpoints in the applications.
3) Reads register values.

How involved is this, and where does one start?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679288%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified the version of VS you are using/plan to use it is a bit difficult to suggest something that will work for you. Assuming you are on VS2005, here's something to munch on: [Creating a Custom Debug Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb145934%28VS.80%29.aspx)